# Why adding items to linked list causes segmentation fault?

Tags: c++, linked-list

When numberOfItems is set to 10000, it works.
When numberOfItems is set to 90000, it results in segmentation fault.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

template<typename T> class Queue {
public:
struct Node {
std::shared_ptr<T> Data;
std::unique_ptr<Node> Next;
};

Queue() : mHead{new Node}, mTail{mHead.get()} {}

Void push(T dataValue) {
mTail->Data = std::make_shared<T>(std::move(dataValue));
mTail->Next.reset(new Node);
mTail = mTail->Next.get();
}

bool empty() { return mHead.get()==mTail;}

std::unique_ptr<Node> mHead;
Node *mTail;
};

int main() {
Queue<std::string> q;
int numberOfItems{90000};
int i{0};
for(i=0; i<numberOfItems; ++i) {
q.push(std::to_string(i));
}
Queue<std::string>::Node *pointer{ q.mHead.get() };
while(pointer != q.mTail) {
std::cerr << *pointer->data << "\n";
pointer = pointer->Next.get();
}
return 0;
}
```

It seems to me that the segmentation fault occurs in the default destrctor of class Queue.

I try to examine class members and push method, but i can not find my mistake.

Comment: `When numberOfItems is set to 10000, it works. When numberOfItems is set to 90000, it results in segmentation fault.` must you use 90000?

Comment: I think, but this is pure speculation, that problem when destructing 90000 objects when such data structure is used is stack overflow. You see, when you destruct Queue it tries to destruct mHead first, which tries to destruct Next, which tries to destruct it's Next and so on 90000 times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Destructing the chain of `std::unique_ptr` at the end of the program blows your stack. You can prevent this chain reaction by releasing the `std::unique_ptr` in the destructor of `Queue()`:

```
~Queue() {
    mHead.release();
}
```

Note that the memory  of `Queue` is leaked. A better practice is to loop through your Nodes and release and destroy them one by one.

Comment: Thanks for answer and comments, destroying nodes one by one solve my problem.